# Scroll modal to top after clicking navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have the following code which loads wordpress posts into a modal which works great. The only problem is that when one of the nav links are clicked it loads the next post without scrolling to the top.

Is there any way i can make the modal scroll to the top when one of the nav links are clicked ?

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on("click", ".esg-grid a, .postmodal .post-navigation a", function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
        var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
                $(".postmodal").load(post_url + " #main-content" );
                $(".postmodal-container").removeClass("hidden");
                //window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
    return false;
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should scroll to the top of your modal. You can put it right after your load in the click listener to get it to scroll.

```
$(".postmodal-container").scrollTop(0)
```

Comment: thanks, it works but is there a way i can do it so it doesnt goto the top until the modal has the new content in it ? because at the moment it goes to the top and then the modal updates with the new post which looks odd

Comment: its ok i did it with $( ".postmodal" ).empty();